# Eclipse plugin can't be installed directly from weblink

Tags: eclipse-plugin

My plugin has the form of a zip file and is located at http://scg.unibe.ch/wiki/projects/DoodleDebug/DoodleDebug-update-site?view=PRDownloadView.
Downloading and installing it from a local file works perfectly nice. However, if I paste the URL into Eclipse's dialog, it says something like "no repository found".

Is Eclipse unable to handle zip plugins directly from the web?

Comment: Are you using an update site or trying to install the plug-in like a automatically launched executable?

Comment: The web link you mentioned seems to download a zipped update site.  In order to install in Eclipse, you should host the update site and not try to deliver it directly.  Check out http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_%28site.xml%29%3F

Comment: To create the zip, I only had a feature project and exported this one. Now, when I have an update site project, what do I need to host on the server? All three projects, with public access to the update site directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to host the update site on a web server.  The content is static.  Then have your users add the update site URL to the software site list.

Comment: So the feature project and plugin itself need to be on the server too?

Comment: Yes, that's where they will be downloaded from.  When you create the update site they should be built also and downloadable jar files will be created along with the necessary metadata.